# Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, linq

I am having issues with the following linq query:

```
 conv.ConversationUsers = await (from cu in db.ConversationUsers
     where conversationCreationDto.Users.Any(u => cu.UserId == u.UserId)
     select cu).Include(u => u.Conversation).Include(u => u.User).ToListAsync();
```

`conversationCreationDto.Users` is a local collection of User objects. `db.ConversationUsers` is a db table

The error that is returned:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type 'DM.DTO.UserDTO'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

I understand that I need to change the order of the comparison, I need to say 'Does cu contain any of these Ids' but I cannot do this because cu isnt a collection. is there a way for me to make cu a collection that I can do a .Any on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project `conversationCreationDto.Users` into `List<int>` with `UserIds` outside of your query  and use `Contains` instead of `Any`:

```
var ids = conversationCreationDto.Users.Select(u => u.UserId).ToList();
conv.ConversationUsers = await (from cu in db.ConversationUsers
     where ids.Contains(cu.UserId)
     select cu).Include(u => u.Conversation).Include(u => u.User).ToListAsync();
```

That should result in `WHERE UserId IN (...)` in generated SQL.